# Sessions and rails: Sessions a undefined variable/method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So, I have this error:

`undefined local variable or method session for ApplicationController:Class`

So what I am guessing is rails, there is no "session" variable until it is  set, right?
Or am I doing something wrong. This is the code using it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Pre vent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  @account = User.find session[:userid]


end
```

I set it in the login page. Would there be a way to only execute is it isn't nil, or would that not work as it is truly undefined? Am I checking sessions right?
The code for setting sessions:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def login
  end
  def login_attempt
    authuser = User.auth(params[:name], params[:password])
    if authuser
      session[:userid] = authuser.id
        flash[:notice] = "We logged you in, #{authuser.name}!"
    else
        flash[:notice] = "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD!"
    end
  end
```

end

So... Any ideas what this error message even means. I see there was a question like this, but that isn't the same, according to my testing (Or is it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`session` method does exist, but it's on instance only, not on class level.

In your code, you defined `@account` at class level. That is wrong.

Do it in instance method instead:

```
def foo
  @account = User.find session[:something]
end
```

Comment: So, instance methods can be used by Class.new.fœõ and class by Class.foo